# Block calls in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, callblocking

I am trying to develop a basic code to block calls in Android. My code was working initially but now it is not.

code to block all calls

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
```

ITelephony is the interface used

```
        telephony = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
```

cannot call any of the available functions

```
        telephony.endCall();
        telephony.notifyAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
m.setAccessible(true);
```

you effectively are trying to bypass Java security. On some devices with old Android version it may have worked, but on more locked down devices it is not guaranteed to.